# Django 1.4.1 error loading MySQLdb module when attempting 'python manage.py shell'

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I am trying to set up MySQL, and can't seem to be able to enter the Django manage.py shell interpreter. I did install MySQL-python but that did not solve the issue.

Getting the output below:

---

```
rrdhcp-10-32-44-126:django pavelfage$ python manage.py shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 45, in handle_noargs
    from django.db.models.loading import get_models
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 24, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named _mysql
```

---

Any suggestions really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the `MySQLdb` module. You basically just have to install it.

By the looks of it, you are using a Mac, so you might want to check out this answer for detailed installation instructions: [How to install MySQLdb (Python data access library to MySQL) on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448429/how-to-install-mysqldb-python-data-access-library-to-mysql-on-mac-os-x)

On a totally alternate solution, as you mentionned Django development you might want to use `sqlite3` instead of `MySQL`, which could be simpler to install.

Comment: @Paul It's usually a better choice for development as there is less setup overhead!

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I am assuming that it is not the perfect tool for running production apps, but hopefully it will be easier to switch to something like mysql once I get a hang of sqlite.

Comment: @Paul From the dev point of view, neither make any difference, the Django ORM abstracts this. From a performance standpoint, I wouldn't pronounce myself on this, but SQLite is good too.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to import MySQLdb from python shell.
Try importing MySQLdb from python shell not django

If you can not import MySQLdb from python shell;
It may caused because of 32-64 bit mismatch,

Try this [link](http://birdhouse.org/blog/2009/02/21/python-mysql-connections-on-mac-os/)